# Grails: Apply a custom constraint to all fields of an Domain class

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-validation, spring-validator

In Grails it's possible to define global constraints within the Config.groovy file which can be used to validate all defined constraints from every domain class using

```
Config.groovy:
    grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
        '*'(nullable: true)
        ...
    }
```

**Question:**
Is it also possible to define a constraint which is only used for the fields of one domain class? I'm thinking about something like this (which isn't working in reality)

```
class myDomainClass{
fields
...

static constraints = {
'*'(MyCustomCOnstraint:true)

}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a standard solution to that.

In case there is not, you can build a loop inside the constraint closure:

```
static constraints = {
  // use MyCustomCOnstraint:true for fields firstname, lastname and address
  ['firstname', 'lastname', 'address'].each { property ->
    "$property"(MyCustomCOnstraint:true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could take a look at :

1. a hack for backward compatibility - since grails 2.3.4 I think  : in your config.groovy

> ```
> // Null object error fix for backward compatibility 
> grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
> ```

This stops converting blanks to nulls - and may cure your issue, there was a reason why this feature was added - for your own app security... so choose wisely.

1. You could take a look at programming Grails by Burt Beckwith chapter 3 covers custom validation, from install-templates  to making extreme custom validation:

> import com.myapp.MyUserValidator beans = {
>   'com.myapp.UserValidator'(MyUserValidator) }

But to be honest I really don't think there is anything is that segment that could help besides  the bit that discusses setting up a filter to convert all input blanks to nulls:

convertBlanksToNullsAndTrim

You could reverse that code so that if it is null make it =''. again with the above point in place if is as per default it could get set as null unless point 1 is set in your config.groovy

If it were me I would try the first option to see if it cures current situation